# Keycloak multiple sessions for the same username

Tags: single-sign-on, basic-authentication, keycloak, session-management, redhat-sso

I've recently configured SSO with Keycloak servlet adapter. 
The problem is that we have service-to-service communication, which goes with BASIC authentication.
Previously, we were using JAAS authentication, therefore the S2S communication was stateless (no sessions associated).

With the SSO/Keycloak, this is no longer the case. Moreover, each REST request, creates a new Keycloak session.

I tried to find a configuration or an alternative solution without Keycloak customization and coding, but I couldn't.

P.S. Due to backward compatibility, I can't change the REST clients to switch to BEARER or other auth methods.

Anyone having better idea?

Comment: I haven't tried, I'm sorry. I have other priorities and I don't have enough time to check.

Answer (score 1):

I read the point that you cannot change from **basic** to **bearer**. But can you switch off your basic authentication altogether from your rest services?

I am saying that because after doing that you may be able to move your authentication logic to a filter.

You can create a [Filter](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html) that would intercept all requests before they would even reach your Rest Service. This filter handles authentication and based on success proceeds to rest service otherwise returns 401.
Sample code:

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter 
{
  if( (performAuth()) ) 
     chain.doFilter(request, response);
  else     
    // set status to HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
}

// But you will have to find a way to exclude this class from authentication chain.
```

Try thinking along these lines, you may get some direction.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @tryingToLearn. This could be a good work-around, but only for the multiple sessions that are flooding Keycloak. I may give a try, once I get some spare time. There might be one disadvantage - additional HTTP handshake to get the SSO token.